# How will this affect my SEO ranking?

Tags: seo, pagerank

I run a fishkeeping website based on a WordPress (PHP) CMS.

I've recently put a fairly complex "filter" into place which searches my content for mentions of fish species profiles and turns them into an active link.

For example,

`asdasd this is a test about abdomen to see if the caudal fin will work asdadasdas try again with abdomen and A. panduro and Apistogramma panduro`

...becomes

`asdasd this is a test about abdomen to see if the caudal fin will work asdadasdas try again with abdomen and <a href="/?p=1703" class="link_species">A. panduro</a> and <a href="/?p=1703" class="link_species">Apistogramma panduro</a>`

On the rest of my website, the species are linked with pretty URLs such as `/species/apistogramma-panduro/` but due to the way this filter works, the only information I can get access to is the `id`of the post. As such, I'm using `/?p=1703`  or whatever the ID is.

What I'd like to know is: how much will this affect my SEO rating/ranking? Will it be detrimental if I don't rewrite the function?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WordPress internal rewrite engine](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) should take care of 301 redirecting your `/?p=1703` URL to the `/species/apistogramma-panduro/` version which would alleviate any need take any further action.

Having a good SEO plugin (such as Joost's [WordPress SEO plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/)) would ensure your URL's are properly canonicalized to the appropriate version ensuring any further possibility of duplicate content.

Answer (score 4):

What you should do it place a [canonical URL](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) on your pages to make sure that Google knows that both URLs are refering to the same page. Make sure you use the one with the keyword as that is your "main" URL. (i.e. `/species/`).

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/species/" />
```